# how can i check database's attribute value C#

Tags: c#, mysql, database

I'm trying to learn C# and I want to ask you something: I connect a simple db to my program, so, is it possible check the attribute's value from a database with a query?

Comment: please ask a more detailed question. Are you trying to get a attribute from a db and save it in an object or do you want to get the attribute from an object but access the db every single time?

Comment: I want to use the attribute like a variable, something like 
if(attribute==0){
    //do stuff
}

Comment: you can add logic like this to an Attribute by using get{} and set {} but i wouldnt recommend it https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w86s7x04.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Which attribute are you talking about?

For creating `SELECT` Commands inside C#, read this article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fksx3b4f.aspx

For easier and safer SQL Handling in the future, please consider installing the Plugin `Dapper`, which you can learn more about here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dapper

Comment: I have to create a chart and I did a query. But I have a condition, if 'attribute==1' remove from the chart

Comment: Just store the data, which the query return inside a variable. `var attribute = SQL_Command_here`.